# c# AutoMapper Conditional Mapping Condition

Tags: c#, automapper

i just want to get Communities count as well as if its community delete flag its true then count will be minus. i had wrote below code, its return all count. any suggestion fot that -
Code -
`Mapper.CreateMap< VPS_Entity.Brand, ZillowBrandViewEntity >()
              .ForMember(e => e.CommunityCount, ex => ex.MapFrom(s => s.Communities.Count))
                .ForSourceMember(e => e.Builder, ex => ex.Ignore());`
class file - 
Brand data model class file have -
  `public virtual ICollection<Community> Communities { get; set; }`,
 in between Community class file have - "public bool Deleted { get; set; }"

thanks.

Comment: ```MapFrom(s => s.Communities.Count(c=>!c.Deleted))```

Comment: Error - Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS1955 Non-invocable member `'ICollection<Community>.Count'` cannot be used like a method.`

Comment: Google the error and try to understand why it doesn't compile. You have to learn things by yourself, you cannot expect help every step of the way.

Comment: I got an answer,  i changed my code mapper to simple binding & its work.

`CommunityCount = e.Communities.Count(x => !x.Deleted)`